# PHP & Google Graphs not displayed on ipad

Tags: php, ios, ipad

Any help would be appreciated.

I do not have an ipad to test my code on, but the code works on a computer and an android device. When the same code is executed on an ipad nothing is displayed.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!!

```
function drawChart(object, type) {
  // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(object);
  var options = {
      title: type,          
       //vAxis: {title: 'Dollars'},
      //hAxis: {title: "Week"},
      is3D: 'true',
      width: 1200,
      height: 500,
      isStacked:true
    };  
  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('graph'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

Comment: To get any meaningfull help, you should create a demo in for example jsfiddle or js-bin that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I will try but not sure I can duplicate both the backend and the front end.